# Is there a balanced way to serialize 2-level object in c# using single class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I need output json result from controller this way: `{ x: { myProp1: false, myProp2:"xx" } }`
I want object passed to `Json(obj)` be an instance of class without nested classes.
Is there any way I can make a class `MyResult` that will produce result I want **without** creating wrapper standalone class or object?

I want all:

- to be able to produce the correct response calling `return Json(new MyResult());`
- leaving `MyResult` class to be single class in single file
- without over-engineering.

Looking for best way of doing this.

Current code:

```
[Serializable]
class MyResult{
    [JsonPropertyName("myProp1")]
    public bool Property1 {get; init;} = false; 
    [JsonPropertyName("myProp2")]
    public string Property2 {get; init;} = "xx";

    public MyResult(bool p1 = true, string p2 = "xx") {
        Property1 = p1;
        Property2 = p2;
    }
}

...


public class MyController : Controller

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("GetMyResult")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public IActionResult GetMyResult() {
        return Json(new {x = new MyResult()}); // I want this to be return Json(new MyResult());
    }
```

Comment: "best way of doing this" - will be quite an opinionated thing. I would say that your current one is pretty good.

Comment: @GuruStron I don't like anonymous object `new {x = new MyResult()}`. I want just `new MyResult()` here, but without overenineering of `MyResult` class and without creating subclasses for objects inside `MyResult`

Comment: Nothing prevent you from using `return Json(new MyResult())`. On the other hand, your desired JSON is *very different*. The problem isn't the anonymous type. It's the attempt to use `MyResult` to represent a very different object

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in this case I lose `{x=..}` wrapper in resulting JSON.

Comment: You want a wrapper but don´t want to create it in your code? Huuuum?

Comment: @filimonic TBH current one is the easiest option. Everything else would be "overenineering". You can create and register custom serializer  for `MyResult` which will always wrap it into another json object.

Comment: What is your actual **problem** about `Json(new x { ... })` despite that you don't like it?

Comment: @HimBromBeere  I want something like easy nested struct inside, like a class or struct, but acting only as a part of `MyResult` class and can't be separated. Smth like `class MyResult { struct x { bool myProp1; string myProp2 } }`

Comment: @filimonic that's not a wrapper. That's a *different* object. You're asking for a transformation, not serialization. The easiest way would be to create a DTO that actually matches the payload you want. What happens when you try to create a Swagger document from that `MyResult` that doesn't really match the payload? After that, the anonymous type is the quick&dirty way. If you really want to force the serializer to work in a certain way, you'll need a custom type converter. That *is* over-engineering though

Comment: @filimonic `I want something like easy nested struct inside,` create a proper DTO then `class ResultDTO { public MyResult x{get;set;}};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult GetMyResult()
{
    return Json(new MyResult()); 
}

public override JsonResult Json(object data) 
    => new JsonResult( new { x = data });
```

- ✅ to be able to produce the correct response calling return Json(new MyResult());
- ✅ leaving MyResult class to be single class in single file
- ✅ without over-engineering.